# Is there any other function $f(x)$ such that $f$ is Discontinous at $x=a$ but $fof$ is continous

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Is there any other function $f(x)$ such that $f$ is Discontinous at $x=a$ but $fof$ is continous.

I know the well know example for this as Dirchlet's function. is there any other?

Comment: ok actually in this forum i have seen one example as $f(x)=1+2[x]-x$ for which $fof(x)=x+2+2\left([x]+[-x]\right)=x$ when $x$ is non integer. But this has removable discontinuties for integers right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=1$ if $x\leq 0, f(x)=2$ if $x>0$. $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and $f\circ f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: I'm impressed that we basically gave identical answers within seconds of each other.

Answer (score 9):

For an example of $\,f(x)\,$ with a vertical asymptote discontinuity, yet $\,(f \circ f)(x) = x\,$:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & x \ne 0 \\[5px] 0 & x=0 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Unlike some other examples, in this one the image of $f $ is $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Right, in fact $f$ is a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and a classic example of an involution $f^{-1}=f$.

Answer (score 4):

The function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}a - 1 & x\ge a \\ a - 2 & x < a \end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous at $x = a$, but $f(f(x)) = a - 2$ is a continuous (constant) function.